# shell-mode prompt?

Tags: shell, shell-mode

I have set in my ~/.emacs.d/init_bash.sh:

```
export PS1='\h:\w$ '
```

without it, my prompt is

```
bash-3.2$
```

but now it is

```
bash-3.2$ computername:~/path/to/directory$
```

How do I make it just be

```
computername:~/path/to/directory$
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply seeing the initial prompt, followed by a new one after your script has run.

The new prompt should be all you see from that point.

Try pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> ?

Comment: Yep, you're right. Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't seem like much of a problem, really?

Comment: I suppose not .